# Coating chicken using an oil and spice rub

Tags: chicken, marination

Follow up to [this post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/125003/96288), after coating my chicken in a mix of oil and spices, I keep it in something similar to a tupperware container in the fridge. The problem is, the oil coating on oneside gets transferred from the chicken to the container surface itself.

How to stop this from happening?

Comment: Sorry, I struggle to follow - you are placing the meat in the container and wonder why some of it transfers to the container?

Comment: The coating ends up getting transfered from meat to container @Stephie Like most of it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a coating on non-stick spray in the container first, or if that fails, perhaps a layer of plastic wrap.  You can then remove the chicken by lifting the plastic wrap and gently flipping to pat the coating back to the chicken.